# Rails 4: two models with polymorphic associations (has one and belongs_to) and nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I have two models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  email           :string(255)
#  password_digest :string(255)
#  created_user    :integer
#  updated_user    :integer
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#  remember_token  :string(255)
#
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :person, as: :personable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true
  validates_associated :person
end
```

and

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: people
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  last_name       :string(255)
#  first_name      :string(255)
#  middle_name     :string(255)
#  birthday        :date
#  created_user    :integer
#  updated_user    :integer 
#  personable_id   :integer
#  personable_type :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :personable, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My SignupController

```
class SignupController < ApplicationController

  layout "signup"

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_person
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      save_user_id
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "signup/new"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                                 :password,
                                 :password_confirmation,
                                 people_attributes: [ :last_name,
                                                      :first_name,
                                                      :birthday])
  end
end
```

My view signup/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path, html: { role: "form" }) do |user_fields| %>
  <%= user_fields.fields_for :person do |person_fields| %>
    <%= person_fields.text_field :last_name %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <ul class="text-danger">
      <% @user.errors.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %><!-- /fields_for person -->

  ...

<% end %><!-- /form -->
```

When I create a new object in the form of model persons, in the form of error will not be returned even if it is not valid. And the person object is not saved even if it is valid. But the user object is saved (though should not when person is not valid).

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my permit params were not correct:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                             :password,
                             :password_confirmation,
                             person_attributes: [ :last_name,
                                                  :first_name,
                                                  :birthday])
```

instead

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                             :password,
                             :password_confirmation,
                             people_attributes: [ :last_name,
                                                  :first_name,
                                                  :birthday])
```